# Multiple where constraints for one generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following piece of extension serving some good purpose:

```
public static TV Put<TK, TV, TC>(this IDictionary<TK, TC> dictionary, TK key, TV value) where TC : ICollection<TV>, new()
{
    TC collection = dictionary.TryGetValue(key);

    if (collection == null)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, collection = new TC());
    }

    collection.Add(value);

    return value;
}

// Omit the following code, it is used within method Put
public static TV TryGetValue<TK, TV>(this IDictionary<TK, TV> dictionary, TK key)
{
    TV result;

    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return default(TV);
}
```

I want to additionally constraint generic parameter `TC` to be reference value so that the user doesn't run into problems during execution of `if (collection == null)` statement in case when TC is value type, so how do I deal with this kind of problem when I want the collection to be both derived from

`TC : ICollection<TV>` and `TC : class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public static TV Put<TK, TV, TC>(this IDictionary<TK, TC> dictionary, TK key, TV value)
    where TC : class, ICollection<TV>, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Additionally, for both (value and reference) types you could replace the condition `if (collection == null)` with this:

```
if (collection == default(TC))
```